# /etc/passwd shell not being used by terminal emulators

Tags: shell

The shell I have specified for my user account in `/etc/passwd` is not being used. I changed my shell with `chsh`, and the changes were applied to `/etc/passwd`. When I login to `tty`, this shell is used, but when I open a terminal emulator, the shell used is not the one set in `/etc/passwd`.

In terminal emulators I've used (`gnome-terminal` in this case):

```
echo $0
-bash

echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

In `tty`:

```
echo $0
-zsh

echo $SHELL
/usr/bin/zsh
```

My `/etc/passwd` shell:

```
lcoogan:x:1000:1000:Leo Coogan:/home/lcoogan:/usr/bin/zsh
```

This has been an ongoing problem for me. This means that logging in-and-out isn't going to solve anything. As for hacks, running `zsh` as a command is not ideal, because my `~/.zprofile` is not sourced.

One thing that might be worth mentioning is when I use `Open in terminal` from `nautilus`, it says `login` and is using `zsh`, though the output of the `SHELL` and `0` variable are still the same.[image]

Comment: what terminal emulator are you using? what is the shell in passwd and what in terminal emulator? what does echo $0 and echo $SHELL return in terminal emulator?

Comment: This happens with every terminal emulator I've tried. That's why I said just "terminal emulator".

Comment: `[lcoogan@laptop ~]$ echo $0
-bash
[lcoogan@laptop ~]$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash`

Comment: 1. What shell is defined in `/etc/passwd` for your account? 2. Have you (completely) logged out and back in again since changing it?

Comment: @roaima: Sorry, I'll do that next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found the issue to my problem. It was my `.profile` file. Once I deleted it, that fixed it.

Here is my `.profile`

```bsh
# /etc/profile

# System wide environment and startup programs, for login setup
# Functions and aliases go in /etc/bashrc

# It's NOT a good idea to change this file unless you know what you
# are doing. It's much better to create a custom.sh shell script in
# /etc/profile.d/ to make custom changes to your environment, as this
# will prevent the need for merging in future updates.

pathmunge () {
    case ":${PATH}:" in
        *:"$1":*)
            ;;
        *)
            if [ "$2" = "after" ] ; then
                PATH=$PATH:$1
            else
                PATH=$1:$PATH
            fi
    esac
}


if [ -x /usr/bin/id ]; then
    if [ -z "$EUID" ]; then
        # ksh workaround
        EUID=`/usr/bin/id -u`
        UID=`/usr/bin/id -ru`
    fi
    USER="`/usr/bin/id -un`"
    LOGNAME=$USER
    MAIL="/var/spool/mail/$USER"
fi

# Path manipulation
if [ "$EUID" = "0" ]; then
    pathmunge /usr/sbin
    pathmunge /usr/local/sbin
else
    pathmunge /usr/local/sbin after
    pathmunge /usr/sbin after
fi

HOSTNAME=`/usr/bin/hostnamectl --transient  2>/dev/null`
HISTSIZE=1000
if [ "$HISTCONTROL" = "ignorespace" ] ; then
    export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
else
    export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
fi

export PATH USER LOGNAME MAIL HOSTNAME HISTSIZE HISTCONTROL

for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh /etc/profile.d/sh.local ; do
    if [ -r "$i" ]; then
        if [ "${-#*i}" != "$-" ]; then 
            . "$i"
        else
            . "$i" >/dev/null
        fi
    fi
done

unset i
unset -f pathmunge

if [ -n "${BASH_VERSION-}" ] ; then
        if [ -f /etc/bashrc ] ; then
                # Bash login shells run only /etc/profile
                # Bash non-login shells run only /etc/bashrc
                # Check for double sourcing is done in /etc/bashrc.
                . /etc/bashrc
       fi
fi

XDG_CONFIG_HOME="$HOME/.config"
export XDG_CONFIG_HOME
```

The reason why zsh was saying login when it was used as a login shell, was because in my `.zshrc` I had this:

```bsh
[[ -o login ]] %% echo login
```

I put this here from the advice when I was getting support in an IRC channel for this issue and I was advised to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The emulators may very well be running the specified shell, but not as a login shell, in which case they may ignore /etc/profile, .profile etc. Some allow you to choose a login shell, others allow you to specify which program - usually a shell - to run.

Comment: `-bash` looks like a login shell to me

Comment: Which could have been specified as a parameter to gnome-terminal.